# Notice: Undefined offset: 1 on array size 2

Tags: php, parsing, csv, file-upload

I have this CSV file:

```
german,6357787,hombre;
patricia,666565656,mujer;
```

And this PHP processor:

```
if((!empty($_FILES["csv1"])) && ($_FILES['csv1']['error'] == 0)) {

      //CHECK NOMBRE

      $filename = basename($_FILES['csv1']['name']);

      // CHECK EXTENSIÓN

      $ext = substr($filename, strrpos($filename, '.') + 1);

      //CHECK FORMATO & MIMETYPE

      if (
        (
            ($ext == "csv")
        ) && (
            (in_array($_FILES['csv1']['type'],$mimes)) 
        )
        ) {

          //ANALISIS
          $csv=$_FILES['csv1']['tmp_name'];
          $file_handle = fopen($csv, "r");

            while (!feof($file_handle) ) {

            $line_of_text = fgets($file_handle);
            $parts = explode(';', $line_of_text);

            echo  $parts[0] . $parts[1]. "<BR>";

            }

            fclose($file_handle);

      } else {
         echo "No se ha adjuntado el archivo CSV. <br>Formato no reconocido";
      }
    } else {
     echo "No se ha adjuntado el archivo CSV. <br>El archivo no existe.";
}
```

When I send to the processor my CSV, it echoes correct information (`german,6351787,hombre<BR>patricia,666565656,mujer<BR>`), but down this echo, it also generates an error

> Notice: Undefined offset: 1

If my file has two records, and it echoes an array size 2, why does the `$parts[1]` generate an error?

Comment: Add some check for key existence.

Comment: are you sure $parts holds 2 element?

Comment: Isn't it when it contains 2 rows?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your CSV file have an empty line at the end of the file.

That empty line is sent to `explode(';', $line_of_text);`, which returns an array containing one empty string.

At that moment, `$parts` has only one element, and its index is `0`.

That's why index `1` doesn't exist, and why you got that error.